# Unable to find an entry point named 'EventSetInformation' in DLL 'advapi32.dll'

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, dll

I was playing with my "Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just my code" checkbox

When I check it everythng works fine but when I uncheck it I get the following:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named
>   'EventSetInformation' in DLL 'advapi32.dll'.

Method:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

I have no idea what it means, and anything I search on internet is based on some C++ projects - any ideas?

Comment: I feel like having seen this issue some time ago. Quick search gets me [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/974). Are you sure it is a regular exception? Visual Studio may shown even caugh exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for comment, it's weird... when I leave it checked i get another Format exception I tried to debug it but Visual Studio doesn't stop at breakpoints - do you think this option has anything to do with that?

Comment: I found a post with exactly the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222456/enable-and-disable-step-into-debugging-on-certain-project-in-a-visual-studio-s but I have no idea how to solve it even thought they posted answer xD

Comment: You just get to see more of the not-your-code execution side effects.  Like the EventProvider.SetInformation() method used in the .NET framework.  It catches the exception and sets the internal m_setInformationMissing field to *true* so it won't try again.  The kind of workaround that is needed when your app runs on an old or unusual version of Windows.  Probably Win7, the new XP.